# Why doesn't a random distribution take the engine as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, random, c++11

Recently, I was writing a policy-based class making use of **C++11's random number facility**. I would have liked to be able to pass a stdlib random distribution as a policy to my class (specifically as a template template parameter). To achieve this I could of course have created my own `RandomPolicy` class a wrapper. But I suspected something was wrong with what I was doing.

That is, it brought up the following question: why doesn't a random distribution take the engine type as a template parameter? Instead, I found that an engine takes a distribution as an argument for operator() (and not as a template parameter).
In code, you would write:

```
std::default_random_engine engine;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 9);
int n = distribution(engine);
```

In code, what I would have liked to be able to write:

```
// std::default_random_engine would be the default template argument though
std::uniform_int_distribution<int, std::default_random_engine> distribution(0, 9);
int n = distribution();
```

Of course, a distribution would then also have to take the seed as an argument (to its constructor). 
Surely, I am forgetting about some problem/limitation here. **So I wonder what the specific reasons were to not make it a template parameter.**

I suspected it might be because distributions shouldn't have to handle construction of the engines, but this didn't sound very likely to me after all, as the constructor of an engine doesn't take any arguments besides the seed (which would be passed to the distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two reasons for that:

1. You hinted at that: the engine may need arbitrary arguments to its constructor, and the distribution will not know how to build it. The fact that most (all?) of the standard engines take only a seed doesn't mean that there can't be one that takes additional parameters. You can even build your own engine with arbitrary constructor parameters.
2. One single engine object may be used with many different distributions. Actually I'd say that this is the preferred way to use it: build just one engine and as many distributions as needed. The alternative of having to build several engines and seed them all may be somewhat troublesome.

It is actually a form of *dependency injection*.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't know you were free to make engines accept more than just a seed parameter. Answer accepted :).

Comment: Is it defined what you need to put in a class for it to be used with the standard distributions? I know that it calls `operator()` to get the value, but is there more that something needs to be used (or is it even specified in the standard?)

Comment: @Xymostech: Yes, they are called _Uniform random number generator requirements_. Basically they are: 1) a typedef `result_type` (unsigned integer); 2) `result_type operator()`; 3) `result_type min()`; 4) `result_type  max()`. Additionally: `min()` and `max()` are constants, `min() < max()` and any value returned by `operator()` is between them (both inclusive).